# Assigning the result of a statements block to a variable in python

Tags: python

In some languages it is possible to assign the result of a block to a variable. Here it is in *scala* :

```
val myVal = { 
             var retVal = None
             // Do an intermediate calculation and set to intermediate result 
             // Do another intermediate calculation
             // Another intermediate calculation
             retVal
            }
```

So then the *retVal* is implicitly returned from the block and then assigned to the variable *myVal*.

The direct equivalent in a *more capable python* - and which unfortunately does not exist - would be along the lines of:

```
my_val = (
             ret_val = None
             # Do an intermediate calculation and set to intermediate result 
             # Do another intermediate calculation
             # Another intermediate calculation
             return ret_val
)
```

But that does not work  (*invalid syntax* ).  We have to instead write a function just for this **one-off** variable assignment:

```
def my_func(fn_var1, fn_var2):
             ret_val = None
             # do stuff
             #more stuff
             #and more stuff
             return ret_val

my_val = my_func(*fn_vars)
```

For some variable assignments I disagree with that for a couple of reasons:

- It changes the flow - and sometimes makes it significantly less readable
- Creating functions for a *single usage* is against my preferred way of coding when the logic/code in question is small. If we need to do a certain action many times or it is a large amount of logic *then* creating a function makes sense.

So coming back to the question: is there a different approach to emulate the assignment of a block of statements to a varaible in python?

Comment: Why do you want a block at all?

Comment: Err, no, there isn’t. Lambda comes closest but I wouldn’t recommend them as they are a single statement. Language capabilities are covered pretty comprehensively in the Language Reference https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html

Comment: @superbrain This is a very common use case in which the calculation of a variable is non trivial. It might require  intermediate calculations each of which would be set to an intermediate result.

Comment: I mean why don't you just write all the "stuff" without somehow making it a "block"?

Comment: @superbrain  Then the variable my_val_ has to be declared separately: it is extra code and awkward vs the direct assignment approach.

Comment: Use a function, or a series of statements.

Comment: @barny  Those work but I explained the downsides off those approaches in the question

Comment: @StephenBoesch What does declared separately mean? Just end with `my_val = ret_val` (or use `my_val` throughout instead of `ret_val`).

Comment: If you just write `...; my_val = ret_val` instead of `my_val = (...; return ret_val)`, is it really more code? It seems like less code to me, at least measured in characters (the parentheses and the `return` keyword).

Comment: @kaya3  An additional variable declaration is required and it reads poorly

Comment: It appears to me that both versions have a variable named `my_val` and a variable named `ret_val`, though only the version without the extra "block" can be rewritten to have just the variable `my_val`. I don't see any of the claimed advantages.

Comment: Yes, I have - but those languages have block scope, so it makes sense to have a block where some temporary variables are not leaked into the outer scope. Python does not have block scope so there is really no reason for the statements to be in a separate block.

Comment: It is a bit more challenging to explain the benefits  of assignment of a statement block to a variable than expected.  When it is supported you think:  variable A is the result of applying this sequence of computations. In other languages you just write it out exactly that way. It flows naturally .

Comment: @kaya3  You got it then - a workaround for that lack of  block scope is what I am looking to see how people handle it.

Comment: I fail to see how it saves an assignment statement. In both cases `ret_val` is assigned the same number of times, and in both cases `my_val` is assigned once. On the other hand, the one without an extra "block" can be rewritten to just use `my_val` throughout instead of `ret_val`, resulting in one fewer assignment statement.

Comment: I'm more interested in focusing on the improved flow than the saved  assignment so removed that last part of my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, so long as all of the intermediate steps are expressions, you could do something like this:

```py
my_val = (
    ret_val := 0,
    ret_val := ret_val + sum(range(10)),
    print("function calls are expressions too"),
    ret_val := ret_val * 3.1415926535,
    ret_val
)[-1]
```

But please don't. The natural way of writing it is shorter and more readable:

```py
my_val = 0
my_val += sum(range(10))
print("function calls are statements too")
my_val *= 3.1415926535
```

Comment: While I understand that this is not a preferred pythonic structure I think this is probably the closest to what the language actually supports

Answer (score 2):

No - what you are asking for is a multi-line lambda (anonymous function) in Python; and such a thing does not exist. and probably wont ever exist.

Think about how Python defines blocks - in terms of intdentation. there would need to be some way that Python could identify a block of code with indentation, with the identifying initial `lambda : line, but with a syntax that would still work in the single line case that Python has now.
It has been investigated and rejected.

The view tends to be that if you have multiple lines of code - that thing needs a name.

Comment: You are correct  that this represents an anonymous function - and that python does not directly support it.  I am wondering if there were some pattern that folks familiar with both python and other languages have come up with to plug this gap.  Re: indentation  that was why I put the parentheses around the block: that works for some constructs in python .    Overall it's likely that your answer  is correct - but It continually irks me and so I wanted to give it another shot.

Comment: I am torn between accepting this answer and the one from @kaya3. They are both correct in their own ways:  this one reflects what the language intends to support. The other one shows what is the closest equivalent to the requested structure - which is clearly not pretty

Comment: Any solution that uses exec is hardly a good solution. It is a horrible idea to be frank. Also you get no syntax checking until you actually execute the code.

Comment: I was certainly not interested in the _exec_ approach  but rather the indexed result one. It's not pretty but is the most direct answer that provides a usable approach.  I ran into my own question here again today in the context of desiring this feature in _java_ . I am so used to using it in _scala_ and it sometimes disrupts my flow to do otherwise.

Comment: The index version is hideous too to be honest - it is a hack at best, and definitiely not readable; it took me 3 parses to work out why it worked.

Comment: Yea I awarded because it's a case of "don't shoot the messenger". The indexed is the closest to what was asked in the question - pretty or not.  An "exec" is imo basically _not_ a solution due to potentially extreme security issues.   It can be argued that _your_ answer were better: ie python does not have a true analog. It's just my practice generally to award an answer that most closely approximates the requested feature within reason (_exec_ does not meet that bar imo).

Comment: @StephenBoesch I am not doubting your motives for upvoting or accepting, I am just giving an opinion which is not worth any more than anyone elses :-).

Comment: Sure agreed that the indexed approach is hard to parse.  Python has some great libraries in Deep/Machine learning  and data munging and of course _numpy_  / _pandas_ as the crown jewels.  For general purpose programming it lacks so many things.

Comment: @StephenBoesch - I am not sure it lacks much at all, apart from multi-line anonymous functions maybe and they aren't critical. The Std lib is more extensive than many other languages out of the box as well. Yes it doesn't have the punctuation strictness of C, C++, or the strict OOP everywhere of JAVA - but I don't consider any of that as neccessary.
BTW - numpy/pandas are the crown jewels if you do a lot of large data processing - I have been writing Python code for 8 years and never installed either

Comment: I won't rehash too much here - coming from scala there is a _lot_ missing. In particular it is terrible for functional programming: Guido did not even like fp and it is quite evident.   Starting with the lack of support of piping of collections and that  lambdas do not  permit assignments or multi-line statements.   But there are many instances where it is quite useful due to those excellent libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have correctly noted, there is no "recommended" (like an intended built-in) way to do this (as of `Python3.9`). Nevertheless if you don't mind using `exec` (bad sign) here is a dumb way to achieve this.

```
def _(code):
    SOME_VARIABLE_NAME_THAT_NO_ONE_WILL_EVER_GUESS_BECAUSE_IF_THEY_DO_THINGS_WILL_BREAK = [None]
    exec(code.replace("return", 'SOME_VARIABLE_NAME_THAT_NO_ONE_WILL_EVER_GUESS_BECAUSE_IF_THEY_DO_THINGS_WILL_BREAK[0] ='))
    return SOME_VARIABLE_NAME_THAT_NO_ONE_WILL_EVER_GUESS_BECAUSE_IF_THEY_DO_THINGS_WILL_BREAK[0]
```

usage

```
a = _("""
a = 5
for i in range(10):
    a += 5
return a"""
    )
```

Upsides:

- it somehow works as expressed in the question

Downsides:

- you have to use a string
- it is possible that you use the long variable name inside the code which will break some things
- eveything bad that could happen when using `exec`